# How can I show the data of a DataTable?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I can't seem to find anywhere how can I get the data from a DataTable, and make it that the data is shown to the user.

**The concept is as follows:**

*Let's suppose that every month I get 100 bucks. With an interest rate of 10%, that's 110. So, on month 1, my income was 110 (interest rate applied). Month 2, it was 220. Month 3, 330. And so on so on (according to the number of months the user inputs).*

What I want to do is display this whole information as a table in the app, on other words, a datagrid which has 2 columns (Month and Income), and then add rows accordingly to the number of months the user added (can be 2 as it can be 8, its the number the user inputs). The user is also responsible for the input of the income, so the income can be 2 as it can be 589.

Right now I have the following code:

C#

```
public partial class HomePage
{
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _ = new Entry { Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric };
    }
    public ObservableCollection<object> MonthlyIncomeCalculus { get; set; }
    private void calculate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MonthlyIncomeCalculus = new ObservableCollection<object>();

            DataTable dt = new("MonthlyIncomeCalculator");
            dt.Columns.Add("Months", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Income", typeof(string));

            int Months = int.Parse(MonthInput.Text);    
            int Income = int.Parse(IncomeInput.Text);

            for (int i = 0; i < Months; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(i + 1, (Income * Months) * 1.10);
            }

    }

}
```

I have tried searching through the whole internet, but the help I get (at least here in Stack Overflow), is all related to WPF.
Hence, I am completely lost in turning all this code into some visual.. Any help?

Comment: I would not recommend using DataTables.  Instead create a strongly typed C# class to model your data, and use a List or other IEnumerable to create a collection of that Class

Comment: Second, Xamarin does not have a native datagrid control.  There are third party options available you can try

Comment: However if there are only two datapoints in each row you can just use a ListView or CollectionView.  A datagrid would be overkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first make a model class

```
public class MonthlyIncome 
{
  public int Month { get;set; }
  public double Income { get;set; }
}
```

and then

```
public ObservableCollection<MonthlyIncome> MonthlyIncomeCalculus { get; set;}
private void calculate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    MonthlyIncomeCalculus = new ObservableCollection<MonthlyIncome>();

        MonthlyIncome monthi;
        int Months = int.Parse(MonthInput.Text);    
        int Income = int.Parse(IncomeInput.Text);

        for (int i = 0; i < Months; i++)
        {
           monthi = new MonthlyIncome();
           monthi.Month = i+1;
           monthi.Income = (Income * Months) * 1.10;
           MonthlyIncomeCalculus.Add(monthi);
        }

}
```

Comment: Great help, thank you!
What about the graphical part? Just like people suggested above, a ListView or a CollectionView? The biggest mess I'm facing right now is not being able to connect the code to the graphical part. How do I make it that the List View only generates columns and rows according to the data of the datatable? Does it already do it by itself, so I only gotta bind the ItemsSource?

Comment: yes bind to the itemsSource. 
if it was helpful accept the answer please